# How can exclude Blind sql injection and cross site scripting in Spring MVC frameworks

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

Respected guys,

I am using Spring3 and Spring MVC for developing my web application.JSP is used as view technology.I am using formbacking object to populate forms.Occasionally I am writing script function and ${commandName.fieldname} to set Spring forms.

But my problem is ,Appscan of my forms reports Cross site scripting and Blind sql injection

For example

```
function setDistricts(){
document.getElementById("prs_district").value= ${commandName.fieldname1};
document.getElementById("malprs_district").value= ${commandName.fieldname2};
document.getElementById("per_district").value=${commandName.fieldname3};</script>'"/><script> alert(2039) </script>";
document.getElementById("malper_district").value=${commandName.fieldname4};
}
```

I am strictly follows Hibernate prepared statement query .

How can avoid these problems.Does spring provides any framework to avoid these?Can I integrate any other framework to spring framework?

I invite your suggetions.

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Guide_to_SQL_Injection